# XQuery: Error "Effective boolean value not defined for array(*): [true()]."

Tags: xml, sql

Pretendo realizar una consulta sobre un documento *XML* cuya estructura es la siguiente:

```
<bib>
    <libro anyo="1994">
        <titulo>TCP/IP Ilustrado </titulo>
        <autor>
            <apellido>Stevens</apellido>
            <nombre>W.</nombre>
        </autor>
        <editorial>Prentice-Hall</editorial>
        <precio>65.95</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro anyo="1992">
        <titulo>Programación Avanzada en el entorno Unix</titulo>
        <autor>
            <apellido>Stevens</apellido>
            <nombre>W.</nombre>
        </autor>
        <editorial>Prentice-Hall</editorial>
        <precio>65.95</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro anyo="2000">
        <titulo>Datos en la Web</titulo>
        <autor>
            <apellido>Abiteboul</apellido>
            <nombre>Serge</nombre>
        </autor>
        <autor>
            <apellido>Buneman</apellido>
            <nombre>Peter</nombre>
        </autor>
        <autor>
            <apellido>Suciu</apellido>
            <nombre>Dan</nombre>
        </autor>
        <editorial>Morgan Kaufmann</editorial>
        <precio>39.95</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro anyo="1991">
        <titulo>Economía de la Tecnología y el Contenido de la TV digital</titulo>
        <editor>
            <apellido>Gerbarg</apellido>
            <nombre>Darcy</nombre>
        </editor>
    </libro>
    </bib>
```

Como se puede observar, el autor *W. Stevens* aparece en dos libros (*TCP/IP Ilustrado* y *Programación Avanzada en el entorno Unix*).

El objetivo de la primera cláusula *FLOWR* es extraer una única instancia del elemento *autor* en el caso de que sus elementos hijos tengan el mismo contenido

```
for $a in doc("libros.xml")/bib/libro/autor
group by $nom:=$a/nombre, $ape:=$a/apellido
return <autor>
          <nombre>{
             concat($a[1]/nombre,' ',$a[1]/apellido)
          }</nombre>
          <libro>{
            for $b in doc("libros.xml")/bib/libro
            where $b/autor/[nombre eq $a[1]/nombre]
            return $b/titulo
        }</libro>
       </autor>
```

Concretamente, en la segunda cláusula *FLOWR* (línea 10) obtengo el siguiente error:

> [FORG0006] Effective boolean value not defined for array(*): [true()].

El objetivo de esta segunda cláusula *FLOWR* es devolver el contenido del elemento *titulo*, perteneciente al elemento *libro*, donde el elemento *autor* coincida con el autor que se está iterando en ese momento mediante la primera cláusula *FLOWR*

**¿A qué puede ser debido este error?**

*Ya hice una publicación con una duda sobre XQuery, bien, tengo otra duda, efecto de esa publicación. Si hago una publicación diferente es porque considero que la duda es de otra índole*

Answer (score 0):

Esta duda acaba de ser resuelta por mi profesor por correo. De todas formas publico la solución que me ha ofrecido para aquellos que les parezca interesante.

Podemos pensar que este error se debe a que al existir un elemento `libro` donde hay más de un elemento `autor`, dará error al haber *múltiples positivos en la condición* `where`

> [FORG0006] Effective boolean value not defined for array(*): [true()].

La solución a este problema es aplicar la siguiente estructura: 
`where some $c in $b satisfies $c=$a` .

De esta manera se consigue que, con se cumpla una vez la condición, independientemente de las veces que se cumpla, devolverá el contenido del elemento `//libro/titulo` de aquellos libros donde el elemento `autor/nombre` sea igual al almacenado en ese momento en la variable `a[1]`.

Sin más dilación, el código del segundo *FLOWR*:

```
<libro>{
             for $b in doc("libros.xml")/bib/libro
             where some $c in $b/autor satisfies $c/nombre=$a[1]/nombre
             return $b/titulo
          }</libro>
```